# how do we submit form on browser close button

Tags: javascript, php

I want to submit my form on browser close event, but I don't get that
event I was trying with the following code but its not working as expected. I want to save all the stuff from the form on window close without `window.close event`.

```js
window.bind('beforeunload', function() { 
                $("#submit").click();
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="checking" name="checking">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That’s not what beforeunload is for. You can only use it to ask the user whether they want to leave the page or not, it is not for executing additional code in that situation. Plus, closing a window usually means all pending requests will be terminated anyway. Voting to close as too broad, because your naive approach to this doesn’t suggest to me that you did proper research.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
   $("#submit").click();         //id-of-submit-button
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: its not working when window getting close by browser's close button.It is working where we are using window.close event on any button